# knockout JS option data-bind set select as "selected"

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following code and would like to set one option as "selected".
Usually I use the "optionsValue" for this, but it does not seem to work here.

```
<select data-live-search="true" data-bind="foreach: $parent.customers, event: {change: $parent.changeWorkCustomer($data, $element.value)}">
    <option data-bind="text: customer_display_name, value: customer_id, attr: {'data-tokens': [customer_first_name(), customer_last_name(), css: { customer_fav: fav() > 0 }"></option>
</select>
```

Any ideas how I can set one option as selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By binding an observable to `select` to hold the selected option value.

```
<select data-live-search="true" data-bind="foreach: $parent.customers, 
                                           event: {change: $parent.changeWorkCustomer($data, $element.value)}, 
                                           value: selectedCustomer">
    <option data-bind="text: customer_display_name, value: customer_id, attr: {'data-tokens': [customer_first_name(), customer_last_name(), css: { customer_fav: fav() > 0 }"></option>
</select>

// selects the option whose value is customerId1
this.selectedCustomer = ko.observable('customerId1');
```

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to mention that it was inside a foreach loop so it was simply: "value: customer_id" and I did not need an extra observable.